# My function returns always FALSE even if I provide the right input

Tags: java, php, android-studio

Using textEdit and getting a double from user converting it and saving it to a double variable and passing to my API ... then having a function to check the validation , but if the number is even valid i am getting a false return ... i try my code somewhere else i works valid fine ... but in my android app is not working the way it should ... what could be the problem?

In android app:

```
String natnal_number = editTextNationalNumber.getText().toString();
double national_number =textToDouble(natnal_number);

private double textToDouble(String natnal_number) {
        if (natnal_number != null && natnal_number.length() > 0)
                return Double.parseDouble(natnal_number);
        else
            return 0;
    }
```

function call:

```
   if(!$this->isNationalNumberValid($national_number)){

        return INVALID_NATIONAL_NUMBER;
    };
```

My function

```
       function isNationalNumberValid($input){

        if(!preg_match('/^[0-9]{10}$/',$input))
            return false;
        for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
            if(preg_match('/^'.$i.'{10}$/',$input))
                return false;
        for($i=0,$sum=0;$i<9;$i++)
            $sum+=((10-$i)*intval(substr($input, $i,1)));
        $ret=$sum%11;
        $parity=intval(substr($input, 9,1));
        if(($ret<2 && $ret==$parity) || ($ret>=2 && $ret==11-$parity))
            return true;
        return false;
}
```

according to my algorithm this input is right (3719768791) but still getting invalid error.

I've realized when i use postman to check the API it is working fine ... What could be the problem ! i Think the android part has a problem !!!

Why !!! when I try to put number from my app (textEdit) it says invalid number when i give the number through postman it accepts the input .. is there anything wrong with my conversion of double ?

i thought this might work but NO LUCK

```
    float national_number = 
    Float.valueOf(editTextNationalNumber.getText().toString());
```

Comment: What is `INVALID_NATIONAL_NUMBER`?

Comment: PHP function bit seems to be fine https://3v4l.org/hucCJ

Comment: It is just a constant INVALID_NATIONAL_NUMBER when my result is equal to INVALID_NATIONAL_NUMBER i print my error message ...

Comment: Is it using 32 bit integers?

Comment: Not sure how to check it?  I am using double variable type in android to get the number from textEdit and using bigint in my database